# How to modify object from two classes in Java?

Tags: java, components, composition

I have two classes and one other object. I need to get the same object (the same instance) in these classes and ability to modify it form these classes. In first class I only need getter of this object, in second class I need setter.Both classes are in one more class(Let's call her the third one) on the basis of composition. I thinking about passing reference from third class to first and second, but during it, it will be null. If I set it to some value from class second, the reference in class first, still will be reference to null? Is it any better and proper way to do this?

```
class First {
      SomeClass object;

     public void setObject(SomeClass object) {
         this.object = object;
      }
      public SomeClass getObject() {
         return object;
      }
    }

    class Second {
      SomeClass object;

      public void setObject(SomeClass object) {
         this.object = object;
      }
    public SomeClass getObject() {
         return object;
      }
    }

    class Third {
      First first;
      Second second;
      SomeClass object;

      public void initializeClasses(){
        first.setObject(object);
        second.setObject(object);
      }
    }
```

But in the momment of initializeClassed the reference is null. So if I after that set in Second class it will be the same object in First class?

Comment: Please post some sample code. It helps us understand the problem and providing you with a better solution.

Comment: Now it should be OK :)

Comment: Are you using Java 8 or later?

Answer (score 1):

For Java 8 or later, you can postpone the actual access to `SomeClass` by using a `Supplier<SomeClass>` rather than a reference. You'd do it like this:

```
class A {
    private Supplier<SomeClass> objectSupplier;
    public SomeClass getObject() {
        return objectSupplier.get();
    }
    public void setObjectSupplier(Supplier<SomeClass> supplier) {
        objectSupplier = supplier;
    }
}
```

and create it like this:

```
class C {
    class A a;
    private SomeClass object;

    public void initClasses() {
        a.setObjectSupplier(() -> object);
    }
}
```

This way, `C`'s instance `a` will always return `C`'s `object`, even if it changes in `C` in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, everything works as it should! I cant give you point, because of too few reputation point...

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply like static object in Third class. Hope this will help you.

```
class First
          {
            SomeClass object;

            public void setObject(SomeClass object)
            {
                this.object = object;
            }

            public SomeClass getObject()
            {
                return Third.second.getObject();
            }
        }

  class Second
        {
            SomeClass object;

            public void setObject(SomeClass object)
            {
                this.object = object;
            }

            public SomeClass getObject()
            {
                return object;
            }
        }

  public class Third
        {
            static First first;
            static Second second;
            SomeClass object;

            public void initializeClasses()
            {
                first = new First();
                second = new Second();
                object = new SomeClass();
                System.out.println(object);
                second.setObject(object);
                System.out.println(first.getObject());

            }

            public static void main(String [] args)
            {
                Third t = new Third();
                t.initializeClasses();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code 
-- Class First and class Second both have reference variable for SomeClass and both are null and are not connected.
-- if you set SomeClass object to the new value in second class First class value will still refer to null.

Solution
-- pass an initialized object so that SomeClass reference in class First and class Second points to the same object in memory (not null)
-- never set the SomeClass reference to the new object in Second Class this will make SomeClass reference to point to separate objects in class First and Class Second
-- instead, change the properties of the SomeClass object referred by  SomeClass reference in  Class Second to see the changes getting reflected in First Class

hope it helps :)